# Django (1.6) custom user model

Tags: django

On my django App, I would like to use an existing app django-voting (installed on my virtual env). But My app works with a custom user model.

*settings.py*

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'signup.myUser'
```

I would like that the installed app use this model instead of django default user model (django.contrib.auth.models import User):

*models.py (django-voting)*

```
user= models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems django-voting app has not been updated for a while. Any app [should not directly reference the `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) anymore.

It is better to change the *models.py (django-voting)* to this:

```
from django.conf import settings

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: Yes i will update the models. I was wondering if there was an other solution.